# SWT Table switching using SWT/Jface

Tags: java, swt, jface

I have table which get's loaded when application starts. This table is created in composite. Now i have another function search button which will populate the same table based on search input. I am not able to populate table with search result. Is it possible to switch within same table depending on functionality (load on application start /search result) using SWT/Jface.
For example
Table value display on application start up

```
 m_workplaceViewer = new TableViewer(table);


               String[] workplace_titles= new String[]{"Code","Plant","Compy Reg Num","Num Of Employees","Type of industry","Type of products/service", "Representative","Main Phone","Phone 1","Phone 2","Fax", "Zip Code",
                        "Address 1","Address 2","Email","HomePage","Note 1","Note 2","Note 3","Note 4","Note 5"};


                for (int i = 0; i < 21; i++){

                 TableViewerColumn column_workplace = new TableViewerColumn(m_workplaceViewer,
                         SWT.NONE);                     
                column_workplace.getColumn().setWidth(75);
                column_workplace.getColumn().setText(workplace_titles[i]);              

               }   

                try {
                    workplaceDetailList= workplaceDaoImpl.getWorkplaceDetails();
                } catch (SQLException e3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e3.printStackTrace();
                }
```

For search button

```
btnSearch.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
                    public void handleEvent(Event event) {

                        String plant=text_workplace.getText();
                        System.out.println("Select Me : " + plant);

                        IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection) m_workplaceViewer
                                .getSelection();
                        if (selection.getFirstElement() instanceof WorkplaceDetail) {
                         workplaceDetail = (WorkplaceDetail) selection.getFirstElement();
                        }
                         System.out.println("Start Search--2");

                        if (plant!=""){ 
                             table.removeAll();
                            workplaceDetailList=workplaceDaoImpl.getWorkplaceDetailsSearchByPlant(plant);
```

> **m_workplaceViewer.setInput(workplaceDetailList)**

```
                            }
```

Databinding :

```
 ObservableListContentProvider m_personViewerContentProviderList1 = new ObservableListContentProvider();
             m_workplaceViewer.setContentProvider(m_personViewerContentProviderList1);

             IObservableList input = 
                       Properties.selfList(WorkplaceDetail.class).observe(workplaceDetailList);
            m_workplaceViewer.setInput(input);  

             ViewerSupport.bind(m_workplaceViewer,
                     input,
                    BeanProperties.values(new String[] {"code","plant","compRegNum","numOfEmps","typeIndst",
                            "typeProd","employee.empName","address.mainPhone","address.phone1","address.phone2",
                            "address.fax", "address.zip", "address.add1", "address.add2","address.empEmail",
                            "address.homepage","note1", "note2", "note3", "note4", "note5"}));
```

Please not that i have only one table.

Answer (score 2):

The usual solutions are to

- call `view.setInput(...)` whenever you have a new result you want to show
- use an `IObservableList` as an intermediate result list for both cases - then you can replace the content of the list whenever needed by simply manipulating the list
- use a `ViewFilter` on the `TableViewer` - though this method can only be used if the search results are a proper subset of the initial content

I usually use the later method, primary because I can completely separate the UI from the business logic which can make the application so much easier to test :-)

Comment: Hi Tonny, i updated my code in Q. I did following change still i am not able to get